# I can't install the 'tqdm' package. What can I do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, nameerror, tqdm

I am coding with Python for 2 years, and I recently got a new computer. I downloaded Python, and PyCharm is working, but in the cmd the 'pip' command is not defined, and I can't download this package from PyCharm. What can I do?

This is the error that I get from PyCharm:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See [Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html). Make sure you are not using the [The Microsoft Store package](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#the-microsoft-store-package) Your description isn't complete, general guideline would be after installing Python set it as an [OS environment variables](https://superuser.com/q/143119). After that is done you'll have pip working, also mind [activating the venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments) on the terminal.

Comment: `pip` is not part of `PyCharm` - you can't find it on PyCharm page. it should be installed with Python and you may need to find full path to program `pip` or use `python -m pip install ...`. And if this doesn't work then you should download from page python.org special script `get-pip` which should download and install `pip` (but this was needed only in older Pythons)

Comment: PyCharm in `Settings` (probably menu `File`) should have function to show `intepreters` (version of Pythons) and installed modules - and there should be function to install new modules.